# How to modify a file in chrome extension using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had the following requirement:

Let's say there is a css file in chrome extension, I want to write DIY CSS and save it in Options Page. Then include the css file in Content Script.
However, I cannot find a way to open or write a file with javascript based on relative path.

The chrome extension provide fileSystem API, but I found that it cannot be run in options page or background.js.
Then I found insertCSS API, but it cannot be used in content script.

So, the question is: is there any possibilities to operate files with javascript in chrome extension Options Page?

Comment: What makes you think the filesystem api does not work in the background or options?

Comment: @DanielHerr  I tried it in Options Page, and the chrome.fileSystem is undefined(I had already got the permission in manifest.json). What's more, even if the fileSystem can be used in Options Page, it cannot meet my requirement since the file is stored in local environment while I want to operate the css file which is located in the extension app.

Comment: You want the sandboxed filesystem api, not the chrome api which extends it. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks for your reply, I will check it :)